# SCTP does not work in PHP File but in Console

Tags: php, console, exec, scp

I want to copy a file from one server to another.
I do it with a an rsa authentification file.
My code is:

**excec("scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -P 22 -i /data/www/htdocs/project/tmp/keydata -r 
/data/www/htdocs/project/data/bild1.jpg user@172.18.8.11:/data/www/htdocs/testordner/bild1.jpg")**

When I execute it in the concole, it works fine. The file is being copied in the folder.
But when I do it within the PHP File, it doesnt work. Can someone help me or give a hint for this problem? THANKS!!

Comment: console is a different environment. different user, different env vars (e.g. path). make sure that scp is in your exec() shell's path, and that things like your console's authorized_keys file is avaialble to whatever user the exec() call is running under.

Comment: in addition to Marc B answer, make sure that PHP has also enough rights in the directory you want to copy into

Comment: Thanks to Marc B!
The answer is excec("/usr/bin/scp -C -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -P 22 -i /data/www/htdocs/project/tmp/keydata -r /data/www/htdocs/project/data/bild1.jpg user@172.18.8.11:/data/www/htdocs/testordner/bild1.jpg") 
So put the "/usr/bin/" in front and it works!!!
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!